# I get the error "Cannot modify header information" in utf8, how to overcome it?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, header, gd

The code works in ANSI perfectly but when I change the encoding to utf8 the following error appears:

- Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampplite\htdocs\alex.php:1) in C:\xampplite\htdocs\alex.php on line 2

-

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(110, 20)
    or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5, "A Simple Text Привет", $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

the output of the code must be the generated image with the sentence.

When I save it in utf8 without BOM a got completely different characters.

For example if i save it in utf8 without BOM the output of the script will be the following:

[image]
But I expect this sentence: "A Simple Text Привет"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a BOM ([byte-order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) at the start of the file. Since it's at the very start, before the `<?php` opening tag, it's output before your PHP code starts executing. Use an editor which allows you to create and edit UTF-8 files without BOM (for example, Notepad++).

Comment: When I save it in utf 8 without BOM a got completely different characters!

Comment: @alexey: How so? Did all characters in the file change? Did some new ones appear at the start? And how are you saving it?

Comment: I change the encoding using notepad++. Not all the characters in the file change. In my editor they are visualized in a good way but in the output of the script i get the mess. The file is saved in .php

Comment: Which characters do change, and to what? Maybe it's an unrelated issue of PHP with unicode strings.

Comment: At the end of my post i mentioned. Russian letters are not visualized properly.

Comment: I expect this "A Simple Text Привет". The english part stays th same but instead of "Привет" i get the wrong letters.

Comment: for Russian letters to see properly use the following at the beginning of the file:
 header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

Answer (score 1):

@delnan is correct.

To preserve the encoding before changing it, cut the text to the clipboard (CTRL+X), change the encoding, then paste your text back in (CTRL+V).

Answer (score 1):

Use UTF-8 without BOM and paste this at the start of your PHP file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```